# Issue when trying to stock a socket into a structure

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I'm trying to store a socket into a structure. I thought this would be straight-forward but the fact that socket don't have constructor (as I understood) make this thing very tricky for me.
Here's what I tried:

```
    struct participants_name {
      participants_name(tcp::socket);
      chat_participant_ptr _participant;
      std::string name;
      std::string password;
      bool logged_in;
      tcp::socket socket_;
      std::map<std::string, contacts_> contacts;
    };


participants_name::participants_name(tcp::socket socket): socket_(std::move(socket))
{

}

void chat_session::add_participants(chat_participant_ptr chat_participant)
{
  this->participants[chat_participant] = participants_name(std::move(socket_));
  this->participants[chat_participant]._participant = chat_participant;
  this->participants[chat_participant].logged_in = false;

  std::cout << "Participant "<< chat_participant << " has connected\n";
}
```

Here is what the session looks like:

```
class chat_session : public chat_participant,
    public std::enable_shared_from_this<chat_session>
{
  public:
       
    chat_session::chat_session(tcp::socket socket, chat_room& room,
      std::map<chat_participant_ptr, participants_name> 
      &participants_):
      socket_(std::move(socket)), room_(room), 
      participants(participants_)
    {
      commands["LOGIN"] = &chat_session::login;
      commands["ADDCONTACT"] = &chat_session::add_friend;
    }

    void start();
    void chat_session::add_participants(chat_participant_ptr chat_participant)


    [...... A few methods here ..... ]


    typedef void (chat_session::*cmdfunctions)(std::string, chat_participant_ptr);
    typedef std::map<std::string, cmdfunctions> functions_map;

    functions_map commands;
    tcp::socket socket_;
    chat_room room_;
    std::map<chat_participant_ptr, participants_name> &participants;
    chat_message read_msg_;
    chat_message_queue write_msgs_;
};

class chat_server
{
public:
  chat_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
      const tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
    : acceptor_(io_service, endpoint),
      socket_(io_service) { do_accept(); }

private:
  void do_accept();
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
  tcp::socket socket_;
  chat_room room_;
  std::map<chat_participant_ptr, participants_name> participants;

};
```

Here is what the compiler complains about:
[...]
/usr/include/c++/10.2.0/tuple:1689:70: error: no matching function for call to ‘participants_name::participants_name()’
1689 |         second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)

I've tried many things but nothing works, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you want to insert a new element into map by `operator[]`, `value` type must be default constructible, it is not your case. `participants_name` doesnt have default constructor. Try `map::emplate` to put a new item into your map, instead `operator[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused here

```
  this->participants[chat_participant] = participants_name(std::move(socket_));
```

not because the `participants_name` object on the right side of the assignment couldn't be constructed, but because the new entry in the map

```
std::map<chat_participant_ptr, participants_name> &participants;
```

can't be created, because struct `participants_name` doesn't have a default constructor (with no arguments).

That's because in the way it's written, `map[key] = value`, the map will have to

- first enter a new pair of `(key, default value)`
- return a reference to the newly created default value
- assign the new value over it.

You can avoid the error by constructing the new map entry in-place, in this way:

```
  this->participants.emplace(chat_participant, participants_name(std::move(socket_)));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was clear and I think I got your point...
But when I tried your suggestion, the same error occurs.. the compiler complains about "no matching function", followed by a warning stating that "candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided"..

Comment: Update: I tried to declare a variable participants_name and not mapping it to any map like so: "participants_name elem(std::move socket_); exit(0)" and the same error occurs

Comment: I'm sorry that it didn't work out. I suspect there are some more differences between your code and mine. I couldn't use your code as-is to test my answer; it's not self-contained; so I had to e.g. strip some fields from your struct participants_name. I'm afraid I can't remote-debug your problem any further as it is. Please reformulate your problem, after looking up https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Here's my solution, including your second comment, in an online compiler. It compiles without error. https://godbolt.org/z/bc1458

Comment: Thank you, I've finally managed to fix the issue.
What you said was indeed correct, but whenever I was trying to access the data by doing "participants[chat_participant].value_to_change", the same error was thrown at me over again, so I just created an iterator and used the find method in order to change the value ! 
Thanks again for your time and your kindness :)